# SSH Key generation

Tags: networking, ssh, web-server

How do I generate a pair of SSH keys to be able to use in several apps (Juice SSH, Turbo, etc) to access my remote host? I've tried generating them with Connectbot, JuiceSSH and on a Linux machine, but none seem to work...

EDIT: I've generated the keys the way I usually do, with `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096`, copied the private key to a `ssh/` folder on my phone's internal memory (which I later point to in the client software) and added the public key to the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file on my server.

Comment: OK – then it looks good to me, and should work. I'm pretty sure I used RSA as well, and almost sure on the 4k. So I don't see where it should fail here. But thanks for filling the gaps – hopefully this enables someone else to spot a thing.

Comment: You need to see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271197/openssl-how-to-extract-public-key

Comment: This should also work http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/73555/how-can-i-create-a-key-par-for-sgit

Answer (score 3):

You could install Termux, a terminal shell with additional Linux functionality on top of Android, with a package manager, so you can scale the magnitude of native Linux functionality at will. Then enter

```
pkg install openssh
```

Key-pairs in different formats will be generated upon OpenSSH install.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install [Termux from Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux)
2. Open Termux and execute `pkg install openssh`
3. Installation scripts automatically generates four public/private key pairs at `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc/ssh/` folder for RSA, DSA, ECDSA, and ed25519 encryption algorithms.
4. If you prefer to do it manually and setup a passphrase just execute `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096` and follow the process.